# Better argument forwarding with concepts and auto&&?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, perfect-forwarding

If you have a function that takes an argument only to then passes it to another function, is it a good idea to do something like the following to achieve more efficient forwarding, rather than having to create several overload versions of your function for each case? Or does this needlessly overcomplicate the call signature?

```c++
void foo(const char* arg);
void foo(const std::string& arg);
void foo(std::string&& arg);

void myFunc(std::convertible_to<std::string> auto&& arg) {
    foo(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
}
```

**Edit**: OK, so there are really two questions here. One is whether or not it's better to use a single function with `auto&&` + `std::forward` to avoid having to define multiple overloads. The second is whether or not the use of the concept would provide better compiler errors if you try to pass something incompatible into `args`.

Comment: Why not just take a string_view?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK, so what if arg is `class FooBar`? Is there necessarily a foobar_view?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica also note that in this case `foo` doesn't come with an overload `foo(std::string_view arg)` anyway.

Comment: you don't need any concept for this.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Not to mention that if you pass a std::string rvalue to a std::string_view parameter then you lose the ability to move like you might with a constructor parameter.

Comment: @Chris_F if you want to forward, I see no reason to constraint. what if `foo` someday accept `class mystring` as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are multiple overloads in play, concepts do not change what will get deduced via template argument deduction. Nor do constrained functions change the behavior of the function itself. Constraints will only change whether that function is a viable candidate for overload resolution. So if someone passes a type that is not implicitly convertible, this function won't get called (and possibly causing a compile error if there is no other appropriate overload).

But it won't make the function execution *itself* faster in any way if they pass a convertible type.

Comment: OK, so there are really two questions here. One is whether or not it's better to use a single function with `auto&&` + `std::forward` to avoid having to define multiple overloads. The second is whether or not the use of the concept would provide better compiler errors if you try to pass something incompatible into `args`. I never implied that I thought this would "change the behavior of the function."

Comment: @Chris_F: Then why did you mention "more efficient forwarding"? That's talking about what happens *inside* of the function.

Comment: @Chris_F: "*whether or not it's better to use a single function with auto&& + std::forward to avoid having to define multiple overloads*" Well, if that's what you were asking, then your example code was poor, because the two are not equivalent. `foo` can take a type which is implicitly convertible to a `char const*` but *not* `std::string`.

Comment: Not computationally more efficient. "More efficient" in the sense that you are writing one function not three.