# C++ concept and perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, perfect-forwarding

I have a relatively simple concept definition of a container type which takes in a specific value type:

```
template <typename T>
concept FooContainer = requires(T cont){
    std::begin(cont);
    std::end(cont);
    requires std::is_same_v<typename T::value_type, Foo>;
};
```

And I would like to define a function that can take in two arguments, each being any container type that satisfy this concept. So far I have

```
    void func(const FooContainer auto& cont1, const FooContainer auto& cont2){
        // ...
    }
```

This works fine and I can pass in any lvalue or rvalue I want into either cont1 or cont2, as I think C++ automatically binds a `const lvalue reference` to an `rvalue` parameter. However, I am wondering how perfect forwarding can be utilized here, so that the value categories can be automatically forwarded into the function.

I knew that forwarding references can only be used in a templated function, but this gets a bit confusing for me as the parameters are already templated concepts...

I tried adding `&&` at different places: i.e. in the template `typename T` for the concept, but not sure exactly what it does.

Comment: `func` is already a template

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145953/better-argument-forwarding-with-concepts-and-auto) answers your question.

Comment: `void f(FooContainer auto&& cont) { g(std::forward<decltype(cont)>(cont)); }` or arguably less ugly: `template <FooContainer Cont> void f(Cont&& cont) { g(std::forward<Cont>(cont)); }`

Comment: Your concept is only valid for classes, not for references (that you would get with forwarding reference).

Comment: @Jarod42 Perhaps `requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>, Foo>;` would be better?

Comment: It depends what the concept should accept, should `const std::vector<Foo>&`/`const std::vector<Foo>` valid for concept, or just `std::vector<Foo>`. So the place of `std::decay_t` or similar.

Comment: @Jarod42 "*should `const std::vector<Foo>&`/`const std::vector<Foo>` valid for concept, ...*" `range_value_t` works for both type, doesn't it?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yes, since `range_value_t` uses `iter_value_t` that uses `remove_cvref_t`, it should work fine.  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e78eWPnPd)

Answer (score 5):

Your `func` is a function template.

A forwarding reference is a parameter of type `T&&` where `T` is a template argument. I removed a bit of cruft from your code to concentrate on the essential:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {};

template <typename T>
concept FooContainer = requires(T){
    requires std::is_same_v<typename std::remove_cvref_t<T>::value_type, Foo>;
};


struct Container {
    using value_type = Foo;
};

void bar(const Container&)  { std::cout << "hello &";}
void bar(Container&&) { std::cout << "hello &&"; }

void func(FooContainer auto&& cont1, FooContainer auto&& cont2){
    bar(std::forward<decltype(cont1)>(cont1));
    bar(std::forward<decltype(cont2)>(cont2));
}

int main() {
    Container c;
    func(c,Container{});
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/vj7fYs8sM):

```
hello &hello &&
```

Note that you have to decide if your concept should match values or references or both. Thanks to Jarod42 for pointing that out. I added `std::remove_cvref` to accept both.

Comment: Concept implementation **IS** important, in the sense that `T` in concept is `Container&` (which cannot have `typedef`).

Comment: @Jarod42 actually I did get an error but didnt consider it as important. I tried to add some `std::remove_cvref` but still same error https://godbolt.org/z/TMbrY6b7s. Where am I wrong? Earlier today I said that I am not fluent in c++20 hence prefer to not use it in answers, now I know what I meant by that :D

Comment: Simple typo `_t` or `::type` missing [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aoK96nPjM) ;-)

Comment: @Jardo42 that silly `_t`. Thanks. I have yet to understand why `Container&` cannot have a member alias, but thats for a different question.

Comment: As invalid `typename Container&::type`?

Comment: @Jarod42 oh well, that makes sense, or rather no sense ;)